# How to add content from word doc and excel as email using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want the body of the email taken from word doc and salutation from excel file

```
Sub SendMailItem()        
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult        
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to run the macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

    If Answer = vbYes Then        
        Dim sh As Worksheet            
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim OA As Object        
        Dim msg As Object        
        Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        Dim i As Integer        
        Dim last_row As Integer        
        last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

        For i = 2 To last_row        
            Set msg = OA.CreateItem(olMailItem)        
            Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
            Dim doc As Object
            Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            wd.visible = True

            Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\usengupta\Desktop\test\Test word Document.docx", ReadOnly:=True)    
            doc.Content.Copy        
            doc.Close

            Set wd = Nothing

            With msg    
                .To = sh.Range("A" & i).Value        
                .CC = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
                .Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value        
                .Body = olRichFormatText        
                .Attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value

                Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor        
                editor.Content.Paste        
                .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@abc.com"        
                .Display        
                .Send        
            End With    
        Next i

        MsgBox "Mail Sent"        
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: The body of the email should be from the word doc(which I figured out) and salutation should be from the excel file. I am not able to add both of these content together in one email

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with that info?

Comment: Done, I have edited the questions

Comment: Please [edit] the question body, not the title, thanks!

Comment: Post a screenshot of where data is located in Excel

Comment: okay, I have made the changes now

Comment: Any leads would be appreciated.